# log4net Could not load type AdoNetAppender

Tags: log4net

I've configured a simple console app to work with log4net. I was able to successfully get log4net to write to a log file; however, it's throwing an exception when I try to write to the database. I get the following:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender].  Tried assembly [log4net,
>   Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44 e1d426115821]
>   and all loaded assemblies

I went first to the dll to check out the available appenders, and AdoNetAppender isn't there, so it would make sense that it couldn't be loaded. I thought this might be a problem with the dll I downloaded from Apache, so I went to SourceForge to get an older copy... and when I checked that dll, it didn't have AdoNetAppender either! I can't imagine this is that difficult. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an issue with log4net and the AdoNetAppender whereby it'll only write to the DB if System.Data.dll is present in the bin directory along with the log4net DLL. It's worth trying this if you haven't already solved this problem.